# How to make Jar files in intellij IDEA without Main class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

In my application I have 3 public classes (with a lot of external dependencies)
that I want to convert to a Java library ( Jar ).
Problem is when I try to construct the Jar using the standard system they ask me for a main class, which my source does not have.

Am I doing something wrong here?
Can someone please guide me on how to build a library using IntelliJ IDEA without a main class and with external dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I use maven in IntelliJ, but you could use ant or gradle.  In all these cases, it is the default behaviour to not include a main.

BTW, having a main for a library is not a bad thing, you can use it to print out information about the library such as when it was built or where the developer using the library can get more information.